# MongoDB not starting on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql, installation

So I'm trying to install MongoDB for use with Node.js, but every time I try to run `mongod --dbpath ~/Documents/nodejs-basics/nodetest1/data` I get this error:

```
2017-12-09T19:26:55.943-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4873 port=27017 dbpath=/home/brandon1407/Documents/nodejs-basics/nodetest1/data/ 64-bit host=xubuntu01
2017-12-09T19:26:55.943-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.6.0
2017-12-09T19:26:55.943-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a57d8e71e6998a2d0afde7edc11bd23e5661c915
2017-12-09T19:26:55.943-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2017-12-09T19:26:55.943-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-12-09T19:26:55.943-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-12-09T19:26:55.943-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-12-09T19:26:55.943-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2017-12-09T19:26:55.943-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-12-09T19:26:55.943-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-12-09T19:26:55.943-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/home/brandon1407/Documents/nodejs-basics/nodetest1/data/" } }
2017-12-09T19:26:55.943-0800 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use
2017-12-09T19:26:55.943-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-12-09T19:26:55.943-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

I had previously received a similar error about the `/data/db` directory missing so I created that directory but got the above error instead. Read through multiple questions asked here, but haven' found anything. It all works just fine on Windows 8.1 though which is strange.

Comment: Have you actually read the error log? Or this sites [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)? Or some basics about Linux system administration? I am asking because the log clearly states the problem, the question is not a programming question but a programmer's question regarding database administration (a subtle difference) and with basic knowledge or at least the slightest bit of effort you could have come up with something like `ps ax | grep mongod`.

Comment: You already have an instance of mongod running (or another service who use the same port). So you need to kill that process or pass another port to mongod with `--port` option.

Comment: The `--port` option actually worked, thanks a lot!